# How can I start Threads from specific point in C#?

Tags: c#, ftp-client

What this code does is, it lists and downloads the files from the FTP server.

The code works fine with single thread. And the logic for downloading file is in "balance_load()" & it downloads file based on an algo i.e. Load Distribution

I am using ftpClient.DownloadFileAsync()

I want to achieve multithreading for specific task only. i.e. not the whole function but within the for loop.
But this code rather executes whole function 2 times simultaneously. Files are downloaded twice.

```
Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(btnrepeat));
workerThread.Start();

Thread workerThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(btnrepeat));
workerThread2.Start();

protected void btnrepeat()
{
    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.0.117/");
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("win10", "zzzz");
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    List<string> directories = new List<string>();

    string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        directories.Add(line);
        line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    }
    streamReader.Close();

    using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient())
    {
        ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("win10", "zzzz");
        for (int i = 0; i <= directories.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (directories[i].Contains("."))
            {
                string path = "ftp://192.168.0.117/" + directories[i].ToString();
                string trnsfrpth = @"E:\\ProjectLocalPath\" + directories[i].ToString();
                extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(directories[i]);
                FtpWebRequest ftpRequest2 = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
                ftpRequest2.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("win10", "zzzz");
                ftpRequest2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
                FtpWebResponse response2 = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest2.GetResponse();
                filesize = (response2.ContentLength) / 1048576;

                balance_load(directories[i],trnsfrpth);
                Thread.Sleep(800);
            }
        }
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
        /* workerThread.Abort();
        workerThread2.Abort();
        workerThread3.Abort();*/
    }
}
```

Comment: I advise not using threads directly but use the [`Parallel.Foreach()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) If you don't want to block the current thread, you could run that `Parallel.Foreach` on one `workerThread`.

Comment: You don't need Parallel.Foreach or threads. You need to clean up the code first. What's the point of mixing up WebClient and WebRequests? Furthermore, you can use asynchronous methods and `async/await` instead of blocking methods, eg `var response=await request.GetResponseAsync();`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think that would be easier..

Comment: Once you clean the code and use asynchronous methods, you can decide whether you need to actually execute multiple requests in parallel. With asynchronous methods, you can simply make many of them at once, collect all the tasks generated by the `GetResponseAsync()` calls and await them with `await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks)`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen it would waste threads waiting for responses. It's OK for quick&dirty scripting, not acceptable for production code, especially web applications. Furthermore, `Parallel.ForEach` will use a limited number of tasks. Network operations don't really need a thread though, they just wait for responses. You can start a lot of them at once

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
balance_load() is downloading files based on some algo. i.e. load distribution....... Can I still achieve it using `parallel.Foreach()`

Comment: I think the solution @PanagiotisKanavos provided, is the way to go. `Parallel.Foreach()` is better suitable for parallel calculations etc. (cpu bound work)